# automatic spacing between Chinese and English characters is not inserted when mixing Chinese and English characters in LaTeX

Tags: pdftex, xetex, chinese

A space should be added automatically between Chinese and English characters, like the picture below which is compiled using overleaf in web browser [image: compiled with overleaf]

But the same .tex file is not correctly compiled in vscode, which means there's no space added automatically [image: same .tex file compiled in vscode]

Here is my working sample, which include the entire preamble part of my document.

```latex
%!TEX program = xelatex
\documentclass[UTF8]{ctexart}
\usepackage{graphicx} %如需在文档中插入图片，则需添加此行命令
\usepackage{geometry} %调整页面设置，如页边距
\usepackage{float} %强制修改图片插入位置
\usepackage{enumerate} %有序列表
\usepackage{booktabs} %修改表格宽度
\usepackage{amsmath} %长公式手动换行

\title{关于板端对接连接的弯矩-转角模型方程的研究}
\author{Ali Abolmaali, John H. Matthysa, Mohammed Farooqi,Yeol Choic}
\date{\today}
\geometry{top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=3cm,right=3cm}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section*{摘要}
本文描述了在拉压翼缘下方只有一排螺栓的情况下，针对板端对接连接（flush end-plate connections）建立Ramberg-Osgood和三参数幂函数模型（Three-Parameter Power model）用于预测弯矩-转角（M–θ）行为的预测方程。作者建立了包括连接的梁和柱在内的的连接区域的有限元模型（FEM），用于进行载荷变形分析，考虑了材料、几何和接触的非线性特性。该FEM模型使用了20世纪80年代在文献中报道的板端对接连接的试验结果进行了验证。通过改变板端对接连接的几何变量，得到了一系列测试用例。通过FEM分析获得了这些测试用例的连接弯矩-转角数据，并将其拟合到Ramberg-Osgood和三参数幂函数模型方程中，以获得定义这些方程的参数。最后，针对板端对接连接的几何变量，建立了用于预测模型方程参数的预测方程。
\end{document}
```

Should I modify my code or adjust the settings of the LaTeX Workshop plugin?

I have tried to use pdflatex and CJK, but the output results are still the same

Comment: Please give a minimal working sample. By the way, the `ctexart` document class is for Chinese document, and has been already finished the setting completely. What you should do are: (1) save the file in the utf8 mode, and (2) complie it in XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX.

Comment: @M. Logic  Thank you for reminding me. I was indeed editing a Chinese document and I have tried saving the file using UTF-8, but it didn't work. I have updated the code for my preamble section in the problem description. Would you please help me if possible? Thank you.

Comment: You should run it with XeLaTeX not pdfLaTeX. You can read the doc of xeCJK.

Comment: A MWS should also contain the texts.

Comment: cross-post https://stackoverflow.com/q/75728829/2777074

Comment: If you post the same question on multiple different sites, you should include links to all other versions of the question in every version of the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I compiled the following sample and get the desired output.

```
\documentclass{ctexart}


\title{关于板端对接连接的弯矩-转角模型方程的研究}
\author{Ali Abolmaali, John H. Matthysa, Mohammed Farooqi,Yeol Choic}
\date{\today}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
本文描述了在拉压翼缘下方只有一排螺栓的情况下，针对板端对接连接（flush end-plate connections）建立Ramberg-Osgood和三参数幂函数模型（Three-Parameter Power model）用于预测弯矩-转角（$M-\theta$）行为的预测方程。作者建立了包括连接的梁和柱在内的的连接区域的有限元模型（FEM），用于进行载荷变形分析，考虑了材料、几何和接触的非线性特性。该FEM模型使用了20世纪80年代在文献中报道的板端对接连接的试验结果进行了验证。通过改变板端对接连接的几何变量，得到了一系列测试用例。通过FEM分析获得了这些测试用例的连接弯矩-转角数据，并将其拟合到Ramberg-Osgood和三参数幂函数模型方程中，以获得定义这些方程的参数。最后，针对板端对接连接的几何变量，建立了用于预测模型方程参数的预测方程。
\end{abstract}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that you should use the `abstract` environment for abstracts.

Make sure that: (1) the version of your TeX system is the newest; (2) compile the document in XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX.

By the way, the following image shows how to save a file as the utf8 mode in the TeXShop editor. Save the file, then the following interface will come out, and choose `Unicoude (UTF-8)` for the `编码` blank.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

the command:

```latex
%!TEX program = xelatex
```

did not work in my IDE.

The solution is clicking the tick in the lower left corner of the VSCode interface, click “Build LaTeX project”, select the Recipe: latexmk (xelatex)[image: Build LaTeX project memu]